# Is this even solvable? Area of 4th triangle given 3 areas

Tags: geometry

I was sent an interesting problem. The diagram has $4$ triangles and their side lengths are given. The areas of $3$ triangles are given, and the task is to solve for the area of the last triangle.

[image: problem]

I first tried Heron's formula but that lead to a system of equations that did not seem solvable. I was thinking you are supposed to make a square of side $6$, which is then divided into those $4$ triangles. That would lead to an easy solution.

[image: possible solution]

But I didn't see any method to justify why the angles lined up--it could be the triangles don't form a square. I was thinking law of sines or cosines but I couldn't see a path to prove the angles lined up.

I searched the web and forums without luck. (Numerade claims to have an [answer](https://www.numerade.com/ask/question/what-is-the-area-x/) but it is paywalled).

Is the question solvable as stated? I've seen my fair share of well-intentioned but improperly stated questions.

(I run the YouTube channel MindYourDecisions so if this turns into a video I would credit answers appropriately.)

Comment: Can you share your source "Nifty who received the problem from Aditya"? Perhaps there's an assumption not mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the slick way is to fit the triangles into a quadrilateral.

(I'm just going to call triangles by their sides $ab6,bc6,cd6,ad6$.)  Start with the three triangles of known areas.  We can certainly fit them without worrying about the angles.  Now from the "central" vertex draw line $L$ parallel to side $6$ in $bc6$ to meet the side $6$ in $ab6$.  Then note that the heights from the side $6$ satisfies $h_{bc6}+h_{ad6}=\frac{2\cdot (5+13)}{6}=6$ so $L$ is perpendicular to the side $6$ in $ab6$ and also parallel to the side $6$ in $ad6$.  Hence the side $6$s meet at right angle and the missing piece now fit together as a square.

Comment: And as an extension, there is the possibility that the point is outside of the square, which occurs when the difference of the areas is 18. Interestingly, this leads to 2 possible areas for the last triangle, depending on whether the sum or difference is 18.

Comment: "L ... perpendicular ... also parallel" is not necessarily true. Call the vertices $A, B, C, D,$ then we can have $DA=AB=BC = 6$ and $DAB, ABC$ not right angles, in which case $L$ is parallel to $BC$ by construction but not necessarily $DA.$ The 4th triangle can have any area between $14$ and $14.734.$

Answer (score 1):

The question is not solvable. "L ... perpendicular ... also parallel" in user's solution is not necessarily true. Call the vertices $A, B, C, D,$ then we can have $DA=AB=BC = 6$ and $DAB, ABC$ not right angles, in which case $L$ is parallel to $BC$ by construction but not necessarily $DA.$ The 4th triangle can have any area between $14$ and $14.734.$

Notice $x+y=6$ doesn't mean the 2 segments have to line up. I have started with the 3 triangles and not drawn in $CD.$

https://imgur.com/a/UpfQsfn

The possible areas can be calculated by brute force, here's a comment (not mine) to demonstrate:

[image]